# spaCy and text cleaning, getting rid of '<br /><br />'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, spacy

I am working with spaCy and python trying to clean some text for sklearn. I run the loop:

```
for text in df.text_all:
    text = str(text)
    text = nlp(text)
    cleaned = [token.lemma_ for token in text if token.is_punct==False and token.is_stop==False]
    cleaned_text.append(' '.join(cleaned))
```

And it works pretty well but it leaves in `<br /><br />` inside of some text. I thought that would be taken out by the `token.is_punct==False` filter but no. I looked for something like html tags but couldn't find anything. Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: you can always preprocess the dataset outside python, like use below command cat FILE_NAME | sed -r 's/\<br \/\>\<br \/\>//g' > NEW_FILE_NAME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
import re

# ...
cleaned = [token.lemma_...

clean_regex = re.compile('<.*?>')
cleantext = re.sub(clean_regex, '', ' '.join(cleaned))

cleaned_text.append(cleantext)
```

Note: if your text contains any '<' characters (other than the `<br />` tags), this method will not work

Hope this helps!